# How to write SASS classes for pseudo style selectors

Tags: sass

I've got a class for styling a scrollbar, can it be written cleaner without needing to class for each selector?

```
/* width */
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1; 
}

/* Handle */
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555; 
}
```

Something like this:

```
.scrollbar {
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { ... }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar { ... }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use ampersand syntax:

```
.scrollbar {
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { ... }
    &::-webkit-scrollbar { ... }
    ...
}
```

Here you can see it in a fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/k3s8rt54/